# How to remove Unity 7.4.5

Tags: unity, ubuntu-gnome

I have Unity and Gnome installed on my computer (Ubuntu 16.04.4). How can I remove Unity without making any damage?
When I search the Synaptic Manager (search unity), this results 500 rows and I cannot understand which packages to remove...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Start in text-only mode

```
Switch on your computer. Wait until the BIOS has finished loading, and press and hold Shift, which will bring up the Grub menu.

Select the line which starts with Advanced options.

Select the line ending with (recovery mode)

Press Return and your machine will begin the boot process.

After a few moments, your PC should display a menu with a number of options, including Drop to root shell prompt. Press Return with this option highlighted.

The PC will start in a terminal.
```

Run these commands:

Mount partitions in read-write mode

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
```

Update repositories

```
apt update
```

Install aptitude and deborphan

```
apt install --reinstall aptitude deborphan
```

Eliminate the components of unity that are not necessary in gnome

```
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(unity),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(gnome))))'
```

Reinstall gnome

```
apt install --reinstall gnome
```

Eliminate orphan packages

```
deborphan
apt --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
```

Remove unnecessary packages

```
apt autoremove
```

Remove downloaded packages

```
apt clean
```

Restart system

```
reboot
```